# Apollo Client: accessing hook function call variables inside custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client

I am trying to create a custom Apollo mutation hook in which I need access to a variable from outside the hook:

```
const useCustomMutation = () => {

  return useMutation(
    GRAPHQL_QUERY,
    {
      update: (store, response) => {
             store.writeQuery({
               query: A_DIFFERENT_QUERY,
               data: externalVariable // <= This is were I need access (simplified code).
             });          
      },
    }
  );
}
```

In a different file, I'd call the hook like this:

```
const someVariable = 1234;

const [mutationFunction, {data, loading, error}] = useCustomMutation();

mutationFunction({ variables: { queryVariable: someVariable }}); // this is the variable I need to access above
```

How can I access `queryVariable`/`someVariable` inside the custom hook (where `externalVariable` is) without having to pass arguments to the hook itself?

```
// I'm trying to avoid this: 
// I want to access mutationFunction variables, not pass a variable to the hook.
const someVariable = 1234;
const [mutationFunction] = useCustomMutation(someVariable);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Seems like it should be a common/trivial matter, but I'm stuck as well.

Comment: I honestly haven´t worked on this for almost two months and I lost my line of thought, but if you want to check the solution I currently have working, I believe the file was this: https://github.com/ndeamador/game-affinity-project-client/blob/master/src/hooks/useAddToLibrary.ts